# Can't connect to device via bluetooth using react-native-ble-manager

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx

I tried to connect bluetooth device directly by passing peripheral id to **connect** method.But after few seconds it automatically disconnect and catch block execute and show **Connection error**.

```
connect(){
    BleManager.connect('58:85:e9:5f:5f:82')
  .then(() => {
    // Success code
    console.log('Connected');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Failure code
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

I referred this link:  https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager

Comment: You have provided a link to innoveit/react-native-ble-manager, but in your tags you have added react-native-ble-plx. Which one are you using?

Comment: have you resolved this issue? i'm having same error.

Answer (score -3):

BleManager does'nt contain function connect() it contains connectToDevice();
check it out
https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/#blemanager

Comment: This is not the same library.